# JQuery Datatable - Header Alignment Issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working in JQUERY Datatable. I had filled the data in the table. Also, i had introduced Horizontal scroll, Vertical Scroll and Fixed Columns.

My div and table is as follows..

```
<div id="div1" style="padding-left: 5px;">
</div>

<table class='tftable' cellspacing='0' rules='all' border='1' id='ItemDetails' cellpadding='0' style='font-family: Arial; border-collapse:collapse;width:150%;'>
<thead>
<tr class='tftable'>
............... 
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
..........
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am binding the table to div.

```
$("#div1").html(html)
```

CSS and JS Used :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Scripts/jquery-plugins/dataTables/dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-plugins/dataTables/dataTables/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-plugins/dataTables/fixedHeader/2.0.6/FixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-plugins/dataTables/fixedColumns/2.0.3/FixedColumns.min.js"></script>
```

My document.ready is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var oTable = $('#ItemDetails').dataTable({
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bSort": true,
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "sScrollY": "395px",
                "aoColumns": [{ "sWidth": "15%" }, { "sWidth": "2%" }, { "sWidth": "2%" }, { "sWidth": "8%" }, { "sWidth": "5%" }, { "sWidth": "6%" }, { "sWidth": "7%" }, { "sWidth": "10%" }, { "sWidth": "3%" }, { "sWidth": "2%" }, { "sWidth": "4%" }, { "sWidth": "5%" }, { "sWidth": "5%" }, { "sWidth": "10%" }, { "sWidth": "10%" }],
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                        {
                            "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
                        }
                ]
            });
            new FixedColumns(oTable, {
                "iLeftColumns": 3,
            });
});
```

This is my problem,

In the result table, the header and the body columns are not aligned properly. I had searched lot of links. But i dint get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this plugin? - https://datatables.net/

The code you've posted doesn't really give enough info to illustrate your problem. Is there some css included with the plugin which isn't being referenced properly? Look in your browser's developer tools and check.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to give much in the way of suggestions without more detail. Ideally, you should try to give a working example of the problem using jsFiddle or similar.

Since you are using the FixedHeader extra, the header row you see is actually in a separate table that datatables tries to keep in sync with the main table with the data rows.

I've found that there are many things that can cause the header row to be misaligned. I'd suggest moving the style settings you have in the table tag's html into a class - that way the header table might be more likely to get them also. I see you have width: 150% - that in particular seems a possible cause.

Are the columns misaligned initially, or only after specific actions? If after actions (sorting, scrolling, filtering, window resize, etc.), you might need to trap these via events, and call fnAdjustColumnSizing() to correct the header row.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I eventually found a solution that worked for me.

My version of this issue was caused by a third-party CSS file that set the 'box-sizing' to a different value. I was able to fix the issue without effecting other elements with the code below:

```
    $table.closest(".dataTables_wrapper").find("*").css("box-sizing","content-box").css("-moz-box-sizing","content-box");
```

Hope this helps someone!